# Next.js 13 and jest gets SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: next.js, jestjs

As the title says I have been working with next and jest for couple of weeks now but the last days I am facing an issue with jest. My test suits run with no errors until I install this package: firestore-stripe-payments
and suddenly my tests brake. I import that package on a firebase.js file in order to initialize it and every component imports the firebase file tests fails with this error
My jest.config file is as follow:

```
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} /
const customJestConfig = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>/"],

  // If you're using [Module Path Aliases](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases),
  // you will have to add the moduleNameMapper in order for jest to resolve your absolute paths.
  // The paths have to be matching with the paths option within the compilerOptions in the tsconfig.json
  // For example:

  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@/(.)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/@stripe",
    "^.+\.module\.(css|sass|scss)$",
  ],
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

the transformIgnorePatterns does not work even though lot of solutions include it.
Any advice would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: No, not at all. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: I do yeah, I'll update this if I figure it out